# Localizable text in a Custom WIX UI Library

Tags: wix, wix3.10

I have 2 projects:

1. `InstallerUILibrary.wixlib` - contains a custom WIX dialog and UI fragment so i can reuse it and the localizable text the dialog uses.
2. `SomeInstaller.wixproj` - an installer project which references `InstallerUILibrary.wixlib` which uses the UI in it's installer product.

I have localised the text in `InstallerUILibrary.wixlib` with entries like this:

```
<Control Id="DiskCost" Text="!(loc.InstallDirDiskCostDlgDiskCost)">
```

And included `en-us.wxl` in `InstallerUILibrary.wixlib` which looks something like this:

```
<WixLocalization Culture="en-us" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/localization">
    <String Id="InstallDirDiskCostDlgDiskCost">Disk Cost...</String>
</WixLocalization>
```

`SomeInstaller` however fails to see the `wxl` file and therefore does not build as the localisable text is broken.

Is this expected? Have a I made some boo boo in referencing my project files?
Is there some switch somewhere which will make it all work?

Do i have to include `en-us.wxl` in each of the consuming project?

Answer (score 2):

Empirically I have discovered that you need to add at least one localisation file to your installer project. This doesn't need to include any strings, just the `WixLocalization` element.

If you don't have any `.wxl` files then the "Cultures to build" text box will be read only. But once you add one this appears to prompt Votive to get it's act together and apply **some** localisation you asked for.

Then what you can do is "suggest" that it build an invariant culture version of the installer falling back on your chosen language. by adding this

```
neutral,en-us;
```

To the Cultures to build text box in the project properties which should now be editable.

So in summary my solutions loom like this:

- InstallerUILibrary.wixproj - wixlib

  - Localization

    - customDlg_en-US.wxl - Contains the strings used in CustomDlg.wxs Culture="en-US".
  - customDlg.wxs
- SomeInstaller.wixproj - Installer - Cultures to build set to `neutral,en-US;`

  - Localization

    - invariantCulture.wxl - Contains a single empty WixLocalisationElement with `Culture = ""` (empty string)
  - Product.wxs - references CustomDlg

If anyone has a neater solution that would be wonderful.

Some reading I found only mildly useful:

- [Using Built-in WixUI Dialog Sets](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/wixui/wixui_dialog_library.html) - Note the addition of the -culture parameter on light.exe i.e. you must select a locale in order for this to work.
- [How To: Make your installer localizable](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/ui_and_localization/make_installer_localizable.html)
- [Specifying Cultures to Build](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/ui_and_localization/specifying_cultures_to_build.html)